# R Memory allocate vector error in Azure VM

Tags: r, azure, virtual-machine

I wanted to run a computational intensive genomics data on Azure VM, My codes terminates in between and shows the following error

```
   Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.3 Gb
    In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
    Execution halted
    Warning message:
    system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

I tried to check the system memory in R it shows the following

```
> memory.limit()
[1] Inf
Warning message:
'memory.limit()' is Windows-specific
```

My VM config is as follows

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                16
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 85
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8171M CPU @ 2.60GHz
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               2095.229
BogoMIPS:              4190.45
Virtualization:        VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:     Microsoft
Virtualization type:   full
```

I tried methods to reason the error as follows

```
> gc()
         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 262523 14.1     641802 34.3   431208 23.1
Vcells 532674  4.1    8388608 64.0  1753958 13.4
> memory.limit()
[1] Inf
Warning message:
'memory.limit()' is Windows-specific
```

No of Cores are as follows

```
$ nproc --all
16
```

My VMs RAM is as follows

```
 free -h | gawk  '/Mem:/{print $2}'
62G
```

my R version is

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26) -- "Planting of a Tree"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

I am not sure how to solve this, please help me to run R, I am a physician and I have very minimal knowledge about this Azure VMs. Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Dr AK

EDIT 1:

I am running SingleR on my single-cell RNAseq data the codes are as follws

```
library(Seurat)
library(scran)
library(scater)
library(SingleR)

singler_rt_lt <- CreateSinglerSeuratObject(counts = counts, project.name = "", species = "Human", min.genes = 500, min.cells = 2, npca = 10, technology = "X10", citation = "", ref.list = list(), normalize.gene.length = F, variable.genes = "de", fine.tune = T, do.signatures = T, do.main.types = T, reduce.file.size = T, numCores = 16, annot="colnames.count.txt")
```

My data consists for 70,000 columns and 50000 rows (Counts data-matrix)

Comment: You'll have to show your code for anyone to be able to help you. Probably you've made a simple error somewhere

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply, Hong, I have added the edits, please have. a look at the codes, it would be really helpful if you can help me out in this. Thanks